# oracle pdb Relocation to new server

Tags: oracle, oracle-19c

We plan to migrate the data (8 PDBS with at least 50 TB Data) of our old oracle server 19c to the new one (same version) and we must do this task  **with minimal or no downtime**. For this reason we can not use simple unplug/plug PDB or TRANSPORTABLE RMAN backup as an option, due the high downtime.

We're searching for available options and the only option that I found which has very low downtime is Relocating a PDB (from Oracle official website).

[PDB Relocation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/multi/relocating-a-pdb.html#GUID-75519361-3DA2-4558-A7E5-64BC16FAFC7D)

Does anyone know another option?

**Update1- (12:00 - 05.12.23):**

- We have an Oracle Exadata Rac cluster (2 Servers - One Online and the other one is offline and sync data with dataguard)
- The new Server is an Oracle Rac Server (2 Servers - Both online - Sync Data with ASM)
- All PDBs are in the same CDB

**Update2- (13:00 - 05.12.23):**

- The Server Exadata is Oracle Linux and the new Server Redhat and they have different storage servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not mention it, but I am going to assume that all PDBs are in the same CDB and the new server is on the same platform as the old one. Build a Data Guard physical standby for the CDB on the new server, then switch to the new server by performing a switchover, which should take no longer than a few minutes.

After the Update2: I am going to assume the most likely scenario: your new server is also on x86 hardware with RHEL (Red Hat is not a platform, it can run on IBM Z or ARM - Oracle Database is also supported on the former). I would still use a Data Guard physical standby for this on the new server. Yes, if you use HCC, that will not work on your third-party storage, but that is not necessarily a showstopper.

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/availability/maa-wp-dr-dbm-130065.pdf

> Upon switchover or failover to a system using third party storage, HCC
> compressed tables will need to be decompressed before they can be
> accessed, lengthening recovery time, requiring substantially more disk
> space, and delivering less performance than the original primary
> database.

Comment: Thanks. I just updated my question.

Comment: @TimLer Still don't know what the new platform is. Exadata is x86 + Linux. If the new server is on x86 + Linux, it is the same platform. Example: POWER + AIX is a different platform. SPARC + Solaris is a different platform.

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention the Platfrom. Yes. Both are X86.